# Unit test anonymous user against controller with authorize attribute

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to build a unit test to make sure an unauthenticated user is unable to reach a controller.  when i run the test, the users is being found as authenticated.  how do i mock things up so that the test finds the mocked user as unauthenticated.

i am using mvc5 with indentity 2.0

controller

```
[Authorize]
public class ProfileController : Controller
{
    private ICompanyServiceLayer _service;

    public ProfileController(ICompanyServiceLayer service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
            /* cool stuff happens here */
        return View();
    }
}
```

test

```
[Test]
public void Index_As_Annonymous_User()
{
    // arrange
    Mock<ICompanyServiceLayer> service = new Mock<ICompanyServiceLayer>();

    GenericIdentity id = new GenericIdentity("");
    Mock<IPrincipal> princ = new Mock<IPrincipal>();
    princ.Setup(x => x.Identity).Returns(id);


    Mock<HttpContextBase> contextBase = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    contextBase.Setup(x => x.User).Returns(princ.Object);

    Mock<ControllerContext> controllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
    controllerContext.Setup(x => x.HttpContext).Returns(contextBase.Object);

    // controller            
    ProfileController controller = new ProfileController(service.Object);
    controller.ControllerContext = controllerContext.Object;

    // act
    var result = controller.Index(1);

    // assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOf(typeof(HttpStatusCodeResult), result);
}
```

**update based on blorkfish suggestion**

```
[Test]
public void Index_As_Annonymous_User()
{
    // arrange
    Mock<ICompanyServiceLayer> service = new Mock<ICompanyServiceLayer>();

    Mock<HttpRequestBase> request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
    request.Setup(x => x.IsAuthenticated).Returns(false);

    Mock<HttpContextBase> contextBase = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    contextBase.Setup(x => x.Request).Returns(request.Object);

    // controller            
    ProfileController controller = new ProfileController(service.Object);
    controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(contextBase.Object, new RouteData(), controller);

    // act
    var result = controller.Index(1);

    // assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOf(typeof(HttpStatusCodeResult), result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Moq, you need to mock the HttpContextBase and ensure its `IsAuthenticated` property returns false.

```
   var mockHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();

        mockHttpContext.SetupGet(c => c.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated).Returns(false);

        var mockControllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();

        mockControllerContext.Setup(c => c.HttpContext).Returns(mockHttpContext.Object);

        controller.ControllerContext = mockControllerContext.Object;
```

Then, running the following in your controller action should return false:

`User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`

Answer (score -1):

The mvc framework checks the HttpRequest.IsAuthenticated flag.  To mock this, you will need to mock the httpContext and the httpRequest:

```
var httpContext = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpContextBase>();
var httpRequest = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpRequestBase>();

httpContext.Stub(x => x.Request).Return(httpRequest);
httpRequest.Stub(x => x.IsAuthenticated).Return(false);

UserController controller = new UserController();
controller.ControllerContext 
    = new ControllerContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), controller);
```

Comment: tried this, and code within Index is still being executed.

Comment: Without mocking the Identity principal, you will get nulls